# WPF DocumentViewer : Navigate using internal link not accurate on first click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, documentviewer

In WPF I have a DocumentViewer inside a Frame control. The DocumentViewer shows an XPS document generated with MS Word. The document contains a Table of Content to help navigate through the document.

The DocumentViewer allows the user to click these links and navigate to the corresponding pages, as long as the DocumentViewer is placed in a control that allows for navigation (e.g. a Frame).

When the user navigates for the first time, the DocumentViewer does not jump accurately to the linked location. The further away in the document, the larger the space between the jumped location and the actual location becomes. It looks like it is off by a certain amount per page. After this first link click, the navigation works perfectly fine.

When navigating back using the navigation buttons on the frame, the link accuracy behaves pore again as soon as the very first view is loaded.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18870095/4711262) post, a new DocumentViewer is being created after clicking on the link for the first time. It seems that that creates an instance that works as expected.

Why is the initial instance not navigating accurately and how to solve this?

The code snipped below can be used to reproduce the issue.

XAML inside a Window:

```
<Frame>
    <Frame.Content>
        <DocumentViewer Name="docViewer" />
    </Frame.Content>
</Frame>
```

Code behind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadDoc();
    }

    private void LoadDoc()
    {
        XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument("test.xps", FileAccess.Read);
        docViewer.Document = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    }
```

The test.xps document contains a TOC and two chapters with around 40 pages in between them. The issue becomes clear when navigating to the second chapter (it is off by 3 pages).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am running into the same thing

Comment: @Dave_750 Hi Dave, No, unfortunately not. This is still an outstanding issue in our product ;(

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  I didn't find anything either.  If it helps, I displayed the xps in a web browser control and it works fine, except I have to wait 5 seconds for it to fully load or it still jumps to the wrong spot.  I also had to add a blank page to the end.  Styling was a PITA too...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After almost two years I've revisited this issue and found the solution.

As can be seen in my original post, I used a `Frame` with its content set to a `DocumentViewer`. The `Frame` is used to enable navigation within the XPS document.

**Some details:**

When the document loads for the first time, the actual `Content` of the `Frame` is set to the `DocumentViewer`. The `Source` of the `Frame` is `null`. When clicking a link in the document, the `Frame` navigates to the location, but has poor accuracy, as described in my question above. Behind the scenes, the `Frame` has changed its `Content` to an instance of `FixedDocumentSequence` and its `Source` is set to the clicked `Uri`. From now on, the navigation works perfectly accurate.

**The solution:**

The solution is actually very simple. Instead of putting a `DocumentViewer` inside the `Frame` and setting the `DocumentViewer.Document` property to the actual `FixedDocumentSequence`, the `Frame.Source` property should be set to the `Uri` of the `FixedDocumentSequence`.

`FixedDocumentSequence` implements the explicit interface property `IUriContext.BaseUri` that can be used to retrieve the `Uri`.

In my code, I use a binding to set the source:

```
<UserControl x:Class="XPSDocumentView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:base="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Markup;assembly=System.Xaml" >

    <Grid>
        <Frame Margin="5" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" 
               Source="{Binding Path=Document.(base:IUriContext.BaseUri)}" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

In code behind you could accomplish the same by doing this:

```
XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(Path, FileAccess.Read);
FixedDocumentSequence document = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
frame.Source = ((System.Windows.Markup.IUriContext)document).BaseUri;
```