# WPF Document Viewer - Internal Links go to wrong page on first click

Tags: c#, wpf, documentviewer

I have a wpf application with a document viewer in it.  The document viewer is used to display an interactive powerpoint saved as an XPS file.  When it first loads, clicking a link in the XPS jumps to the wrong spot.  After that first click, it then works fine.

This question has no answer [WPF DocumentViewer : Navigate using internal link not accurate on first click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518575/wpf-documentviewer-navigate-using-internal-link-not-accurate-on-first-click) and is exactly what I am experiencing.

I have searched high and low and tried to trick it into working by navigating pages with code multiple different ways, but it only ever corrects itself by actually clicking on the internal links.  Has anyone been through this before?